# Is it possible to get a specific page of a pdf without splitting the file?

Tags: java, pdf, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Is it possible to get a single page from a pdf as a file object, not generating temporary files? My current solution is to split the file (using pdftk) so each file generated represents a single page.

The pseudocode of what I want would be something like this:

```
File file = new File(filepath);
File page_two = file.getPage(2)
```

Comment: you can use different tools or java/groovy code but you have to split. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_splitting_a_pdf_document.htm

Comment: Java file objects are specifically there as an abstraction over file system files. In other words, you question is essentially asking if we can have a file object representing something that is not a file system file. The short answer is no, you would need to use some other class/data structure for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @daggett said (and his comment is really the answer to this question).

As a groovy script this could be written as:

```
@Grab('org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.23')
import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument

def doc = PDDocument.load(new File('rfc7995.pdf'))

new Splitter().split(doc).withIndex(1).each { pageDoc, pageNumber -> 
  pageDoc.save("page_${pageNumber}.pdf")
}

doc.close()
```

executing this script looks as follows:

```
─➤ ls -1
rfc7995.pdf
solution.groovy

─➤ groovy solution.groovy 

─➤ ls -1
page_1.pdf
page_2.pdf
page_3.pdf
page_4.pdf
page_5.pdf
page_6.pdf
page_7.pdf
page_8.pdf
page_9.pdf
page_10.pdf
page_11.pdf
page_12.pdf
page_13.pdf
page_14.pdf
page_15.pdf
page_16.pdf
page_17.pdf
page_18.pdf
page_19.pdf
page_20.pdf
page_21.pdf
page_22.pdf
rfc7995.pdf
solution.groovy

─➤
```

where the [original document](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc7995.pdf) had 22 pages.

Or if you just wanted to extract/save a specific page:

```
@Grab('org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.23')
import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument

def doc = PDDocument.load(new File('rfc7995.pdf'))

def pages = new Splitter().split(doc)

// extract page 4 as a PDDocument
def page4 = pages[3]

// and if we feel like saving it
page4.save("page_4.pdf")

doc.close()
```